# Standard input gets stacked

Tags: java, input, console

i have problem with my program, specificly with Standart input.

```
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int in;
    while ((in = input.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.println(((char) in));
        System.out.println("going throught while loop");
    }   
    System.out.println("while loop ended");
    input.close();
```

I would have expected that after input has been printed, the line "while loop ended" would be printed as well, but here is what i get when i wrote "hi" into eclipse console as input

...............................

```
hi
h
going throught while loop
i
going throught while loop
going throught while loop
going throught while loop
```

.........................

and the program still runing, and waiting for another input, so the rest of the code under while loop is not executed, so I am asking you how to make it just one time input, that I input some word or so and then the code will leave while loop, in other words, the line "while loop ended" will be printed.

Thank you all for any advise.

Comment: read() method- reads a single character. so for every character loop is executed, it will continue until your input characher is != -1

Comment: What did you do to terminal the input? On DOS it's ^Z and on Unix it's ^D

Answer (score 1):

According to [ASCII](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/lowercase-letter-i-minuscule-ascii-code-105.html.), your buffer is reading 104(h) 105(i) and 10(LF) and 13(CR). That is, you are reading 'hi' plus the line terminator and next line. You could change your while to the following structure:

```
while ((in = input.read()) != -1 && in != 13 && in != 10)
```

I have seen it when I changed the your sysout to print the int value.

If you can read all the line and print each char in the String, do as follow:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = input.nextLine();
for(char ch: text.toCharArray()){
    System.out.println(ch);
    System.out.printf("going throught while loop \n");
}   
System.out.println("while loop ended");
input.close();
```

Comment: i am ok whith that , i need program to leave while loop after the first input is given and continue with code below

Comment: @Fredegar, take a look at my edit..you can change the code to use scanner..you read all the line and take all the string at once.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a `BufferedReader`, you may just call its `readLine` method to obtain the line the user has typed. If you only need one line, you don’t need a loop.

Another option is looking into `java.util.Scanner`.

Whether you go with one or the other, there are plenty of tutorials and code examples out there for you to use.